# Is it possible to reorder items in a listview builder by dragging them in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list view builder that builds the list, from a persistent local SQFLite database, whenever the app is started. One can add more items to the list and the listview is updated using setState to reflect the changes and the new item is added to the SQFLite database as well. Also, every item in the SQFLite database is given a unique Id. I'd now want to implement a way so that it's possible to rearrange the items of the listview and make it possible to reorder them by moving them up or down the list by holding and dragging them. On reordering them, it would be relatively easy to update their positions on the database but how should the actual dragging, dropping and reordering be done in the listview builder?

The ReorderableListView class can be used to reorder lists that are relatively small and don't work with listview builders. So how can this be achieved when the list is relatively large and is built using a ListView builder?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out implementation using ReorderableListView [ReorderableListSimple demo (requires flutter 1.0.0, flutter_reorderable_list 0.1.1) For ReorderableListView](https://gist.github.com/ffeu/e6ab522bdbcdfdfc7056bcc7ff2f67c7)

Comment: When writing answers please submit more than just a link in case that the link won't work anymore in the future. Maybe add an explanation to what it does. Thank you.

Comment: Links may be broken in future. So, instead of providing link, post Code. Adding explanation is plus.